# What is the status of HTML 5 File API today in differnt browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on the File API. After initial investigation found that the Chrome, Firefox (new versions ) have good support for this. However IE, Opera have not implemented it and Safari have partial support for this.
Can some one please let me know

1. Do opera and IE support the File API ? Is it in plan for future release?
2. Safari says to have partially implemented the File API. How much this partial this is implemented ? Have they implemented XHRHttpRequest.send(File) method ? So that we can send the file object to server.

My understanding is that the Chrome and Firefox are only two browsers today to have support for the drag drop file to web browsers feature.  I that right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) successfully implemented in [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers as of today.In [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29) it is partially implemented and for other browser it is not implemented yet. You can check detail in "[Comparison of layout engines (HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29)".

Comment: Good answer. Also nice to someone from BD.

Answer (score 3):

Here is all the gory details in an "easy" to digest way.  Well nothing about HTML5 support is really easy, but this is the best source for version information:

http://caniuse.com/fileapi

Answer (score 0):

For status on File API and any other HTML5 API's keep a tab on [HTML5 Readiness](http://html5readiness.com/)